# about calling methods and JButtons

Tags: java

It might be a stupid question but i could not understand the syntax in the "Mainframe class"as shown in image:
[Here, the setStringListener method is called from toolbar reference. But the syntax used inside the circular bracket is quite weird to me. I usually have parameters like strings or reference inside the call method. I did not understand how JButton will call this method. This programms works fine. I jst dont understand that part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYvcc.png) The entire source code is typed below.

```
public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {

            new MainFrame();
        }
    });
}}




public class MainFrame extends JFrame{
private TextPanel textPanel;
private Toolbar toolbar;
public MainFrame(){
    super("Hello World");
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    toolbar =new Toolbar();
    textPanel=new TextPanel();
    toolbar.setStringListener(new StringListener(){             
        public void textEmitted(String text){
            textPanel.appendText(text);
        }
    });

    add(toolbar,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(textPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setSize(600, 500);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
}}




public class TextPanel extends JPanel {
private JTextArea textArea;

public TextPanel(){
    textArea=new JTextArea();

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(new JScrollPane(textArea),BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

public void appendText(String text){
    textArea.append(text);
}}



public class Toolbar extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
private JButton helloButton;
private JButton goodbyeButton;
private StringListener textListener;
public Toolbar(){
    helloButton=new JButton("Hello");
    goodbyeButton=new JButton("Goodbye");

    helloButton.addActionListener(this);
    goodbyeButton.addActionListener(this);


    setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    add(helloButton);
    add(goodbyeButton);
}
public void setStringListener(StringListener listener){
    this.textListener=listener;
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JButton clicked=(JButton)e.getSource();
    if (clicked==helloButton){
        if (textListener!=null){
            textListener.textEmitted("Hello\n");
        }
    }
    else if(clicked==goodbyeButton){
        if (textListener!=null){
            textListener.textEmitted("goodBye\n");
        }           
    }       
}}
```

And the interface is StringListener

```
public interface StringListener {
public void textEmitted(String text);
```

}

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html#syntax-of-anonymous-classes

Answer (score 0):

Since you are essentially creating a `new` interface inside your `setStringListener()` method, you need to have an implementation.

---

You can imagine that you've already defined an interface with an implementation of the `textEmitted()` method:

```
public class MyImplementation implements StringListener {

    @Override
    public void textEmitted(String text) {
        // Do stuff here
    }
}
```

Now, instead of defining this interface separately, you can create a new `StringListener` in your `MainFrame` class:

```
StringListener myImplementation = new StringListener() {

    @Override
    public void textEmitted(String text) {
        // Do stuff here
    }
};

toolbar.setStringListener(myImplementation);
```

So what *you*'re doing is basically the same as the above code, but creating the `StringListener` inside your method instead of defining it separately:

```
toolbar.setStringListener(new StringListener() {
    @Override
    public void textEmitted(String text) {
        // Do stuff here
    }
});
```

---

I hope the examples help.

If you're still unsure, I would highly recommend reading through the [Java tutorial for Anonymous Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).